# How to have variable in sql script?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sqlplus

DB: Oracle 11gR2

OS: Linux

Client: sqlplus

In ksh script we can have something like below

> ```
> DOW=`date +%a`
> LOG= /home/output/$DOW
> ```

Is it possible to have such $DOW variable use in SQL script?

Basically I'm running sql script and spooling log to one location, but with above change I would like to change log location to DOW(Day Of Week) directory on whatever day it runs.

> ```
> e.g. spool /home/output/$DOW/test.log
>
> On tuesday script creates log under Tue directory /home/output/Tue/test.log
> ```

Comment: It's all possible if you use the `<< EOF` structure from within the OS script. At least, on Bash that is, I'm just assuming Ksh allows that as well. So, you just write an OS script that also runs SQL commands. When you do that, you can use any OS variable you want. Otherwise, you'll need to pass OS variables to an SQLPLUS file as parameters, like : `mysqlfile.sql $DOW $LOG $PATH`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "I am a shell script"
sqlplus user/pass@something << EOF
spool /home/output/$DOW/test.log
select 9 from dual;
spool off
exit
EOF
```

- The sqlplus connect may be how you like; `sqlplus user` or `sqlplus / as sysdba` or ..
- The last EOF should be placed against the left screen border
- I'm assuming this works for Bash and Korn shell
- It may work without using `EXIT`
- Same for `SPOOL OFF`

Comment: ,thank you for your comments. I think I didn't explained correctly or I didn't understood your comment. I only have a single sql file and it's not been executed by any ksh or bash script. I can certainly create another ksh script and call sql from there and solve my problem.   My question was 1. Within .sql file is it possible to create $DOW variable and generate log in correct day directory (e.g. Mon, Tue.. )

Comment: Ah OK. So you're only working inside the SQL file. In that case, on Linux/Unix you can use the `!` or `host` command to be able to run OS commands. Example : `SQL> host echo $PATH` or `SQL> ! echo $PATH` --- Or, more complete : `SQL> ! echo define PATH=$PATH > temp.sql` then run `start temp.sql` and then variable PATH is defined : `select '&PATH'  from dual;` will show : old   1: select '&PATH'  from dual
new   1: select '/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bi ..

Comment: excellent idea about ! or host command, I will test it out and update it. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back on test result, still remember my above comment and will get back to it.